# How to combine first and second select statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, group-by

The first select statement fills in nulls and the second select statement removes duplicates. How can I run the second SQL statement off of the first or is there a way to combined them?

Here is the SQL Fiddle: [Fiddle SQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/78cfea/9/0)

**FIRST SELECT**

```
/*
 Fill in null values with last record that is not null
*/
SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, 

ISNULL(Address, 
(
SELECT TOP (1) Address    
 FROM test   
 WHERE (FirstName = MainTable.FirstName) AND (Address IS NOT NULL) AND (Address <> '')

ORDER BY Id DESC)

) AS Address

FROM test AS MainTable
```

**Second SELECT**

```
 /*
Return a single record
*/
SELECT FirstName, LastName, MAX(Address) 
FROM test
Group By FirstName, LastName
```

RESULT EXPECTED:

```
| 4, john, doe, 9Street, SC | 
| 5, marry, doe, 78Street, DC |
```

Comment: What's your expect result?

Comment: | 4, john, doe, 9Street, SC |
     |  5, marry, doe, 78Street, DC |

Basically those two select statements fill in the null values and then remove duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server version 2012 or higher you can use `last_value()` to get the last value in a partition (here by `firstname` and `lastname`) of ordered rows (here by `id`).

Unfortunately it doesn't allow to ignore `NULL`s. But we can fix this if we sort rows where the column of interest `IS NULL` before those where it isn't. We can do so by first ordering by a `CASE` returning a lower value, if the column `IS NULL` and a higher value, if it isn't. The second column we then `ORDER BY` is `id`.

To get only one row per `firstname` and `lastname` a simple `DISTINCT` will do then, as the `address` and `city` is the same in any row sharing `firstname` and `lastname`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       t1.firstname,
       t1.lastname,
       last_value(t1.address) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.firstname,
                                                 t1.lastname
                                    ORDER BY CASE
                                            WHEN t1.address IS NULL THEN
                                              -1
                                            ELSE
                                              1
                                            END,
                                            t1.id
                                    RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                                          AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) address,
       last_value(t1.city) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.firstname,
                                              t1.lastname
                                 ORDER BY CASE
                                            WHEN t1.city IS NULL THEN
                                              -1
                                            ELSE
                                              1
                                          END,
                                          t1.id
                                 RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                                               AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) city
       FROM test t1;
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you want latest (by Id) address and city that is not null, right? If so:

```
SELECT max(t1.id) as id, t1.firstName, t1.lastName, adr.address, cty.City 
FROM test t1
cross apply (select top(1) address from test t2 
             where t1.FirstName = t2.FirstName and 
                   t1.LastName = t2.LastName and
                   t2.address is not null
             order by id desc) adr(Address)
cross apply (select top(1) city from test t2 
             where t1.FirstName = t2.FirstName and 
                   t1.LastName = t2.LastName and
                   t2.city is not null
             order by id desc) cty(City)
group by t1.firstName, t1.lastName, adr.address, cty.City;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `SQL Server 2012` or higher, `sticky bit` answer looks to be the best one. If you are using lower version then you can check the below answer.

```
SELECT 
CAST((CASE
  WHEN CHARINDEX('$', Id) > 0
  THEN RIGHT(Id, CHARINDEX('$', REVERSE(Id)) - 1)
  ELSE Id
  END
) AS INT) AS Id,
Firstname, Lastname,
(CASE
  WHEN CHARINDEX('$', Address) > 0
  THEN RIGHT(Address, CHARINDEX('$', REVERSE(Address)) - 1)
  ELSE Address
  END
) AS Address,
(CASE
  WHEN CHARINDEX('$', City) > 0
  THEN RIGHT(City, CHARINDEX('$', REVERSE(City)) - 1)
  ELSE City
  END
) AS City
FROM (

SELECT A.Firstname, A.Lastname, 
STUFF((
  SELECT '$' + CAST(B.Id AS VARCHAR)
  FROM test B 
  WHERE B.Firstname = A.Firstname
  AND
  B.Lastname = A.Lastname
  For XML Path('')),1,1,'') AS Id,
STUFF((
  SELECT '$' + B.Address
  FROM test B 
  WHERE B.Firstname = A.Firstname
  AND
  B.Lastname = A.Lastname
  For XML Path('')),1,1,'') AS Address,
STUFF((
  SELECT '$' + B.City
  FROM test B 
  WHERE B.Firstname = A.Firstname
  AND
  B.Lastname = A.Lastname
  For XML Path('')),1,1,'') AS City
FROM test A  
GROUP BY A.Firstname, A.Lastname
) T
```

Answer (score 0):

I think title is wrong, it should be like "how to get latest value of different columns".

Also hope your table should contain `EmpID` or `USERID` so that index can be created on them.

Or Table can be further normalised if possible.

```
Create table Table1(Empid int pk,FirstName,LastName)

Create table Table2(id int identity(1,1),EMPID FK,Adress,city)
```

Querying on these two tables will be very efficient.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.Firstname
    ,t.Lastname
    ,t1.Address
    ,t2.City
FROM #test t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 t1.Address
    FROM #test t1
    WHERE t1.Address IS NOT NULL
        AND t.Firstname = t1.Firstname
        AND t.Lastname = t1.Lastname
    ORDER BY t1.id DESC
    ) t1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 t2.City
    FROM #test t2
    WHERE t2.City IS NOT NULL
        AND t.Firstname = t2.Firstname
        AND t.Lastname = t2.Lastname
    ORDER BY t2.id DESC
    ) t2
```